# npm start not working for react native setup

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Hei,
I'm new to programming and trying to Setup my toolchain and create a new React Native project.

- If needed, install code editor (+ extensions), git, npm
- Install the Expo app to your phone. iOS or Android
- Use the expo CLI tool to generate an app skeleton
- Create a folder for your React Native projects
- use Git Bash or terminal to go to this folder cd foldername/otherfoldername/etc...
- npm install -g expo-cli
- expo init MyApp --npm
- choose 'blank' template
- if this fails on Windows due to missing interactive mode, use cmd instead of Git Bash
  Test that app works; run it and open in the browser (the interactive shell is needed to get the menu option (w) for launching in browser)
- cd MyApp
- npm start <---
- From now on open 'MyApp' folder in your editor/IDE to edit your project
  Create a remote git repository (Github) and push your app there

I have done these but I get this error when I write in my VScode npm run

- expo start
- Starting project at C:\Users\35845\Documents\ReactNativeProject\MyApp
- Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
- Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
- Error: spawn powershell ENOENT
- at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
- ```
  at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)*     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  ```
- npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
- npm ERR! errno 1
- npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
- npm ERR! Exit status 1
- npm ERR!
- npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
- npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
- npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
- npm ERR!     C:\Users\35845\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-08-26T08_53_44_736Z-debug.log

Can someone please help me with this. Thank you

Comment: Did u run `npm install` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I also installed node.js again and downgraded it

Comment: did install succeed without errors?

Comment: Yes no errors, downloaded all the packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use cmd instead of git bash or PowerShell on windows and try below steps and run:-

```
Delete node_modules folder
run npm cache clean --force
npm install
expo start
```

make sure you are inside your application folder (where package.json is present)

Comment: I used the steps like this to resolve the npm start command issue: 

1.I deleted the node_modules folder from my project.
2.npm cache clean --force
3.npm install
4.npm start. 

Above steps did the trick to make it work with react native npm start command.